# SPARQL CONSTRUCT command order of triples in created resource

Tags: sparql

My SPARQL code out of the Learning SPARQL book:

```
Contruct
{ 
?s dm:problem dm:prob29 . 
 dm:prob29 rdfs:label "Location value must be a URI." . 

}

WHERE
{
  ?s dm:location ?city .
  FILTER (!(isURI(?city)))
}
```

-- creates a file like this:

```
dm:prob29  rdfs:label  "Location value must be a URI." .

d:item693  dm:problem  dm:prob29 .enter
```

Why does he create the `"Location value must be URI"` triple first, when in the `Contruct` command `dm:prob29` etc. is shown first? I am not really sure how this work?

Comment: Because `CONSTRUCT` returns a **set** of RDF triples (an RDF graph also contains just a **set** of RDF triples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of such triples is arbitrary, and has no importance nor meaning, in the context of a `CONSTRUCT` query's output.

Answer (score 0):

Although @TallTed's right that there's no meaning to order of triples in an RDF graph, it can still be very useful to be able to order them - e.g. to compare two graphs in a text editor. One approach is to use ntriples as the serialisation:

1. run your SPARQL construct query
2. select ntriples as serialisation format if SPARQL editor offers it...
3. OR convert TTL or similar to ntriples with something like `riot --output=NTRIPLES a.ttl > a.nt`
4. sort ntriples: e.g. `sort a.nt > a-sorted.nt`